# Is it safe to exercise after taking bath?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, yoga

I read in some yoga books that it is not recommended to exercise after taking a bath. Is there  reason to this. Is it safe to exercise after bath.

I am interested if a prior bath delays the time where I can safely do yoga asanas or body-weight exercises?

Comment: Unless it was a ridiculously hot bath (same for any body-temp-increasing thing, like a sauna) I fail to see what the issue could be.

Comment: Are you just talking about a normal bath for cleaning, with warm water, for 5-10 minutes?

Comment: @Kate I don't have that information because of that my question is general.

Comment: I agree with Dave, do you have any reason to think its not safe? Because its probably more worthwhile to deal with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a hot-tub session, there may be some reasons to not exercise immediately, but I can't think of any reason why you would need to avoid exercise after a normal bath.